# Trying to use JS .scroll() on pure CSS parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm using [Keith Clark's pure CSS parallax](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) to create a web page, but I'm also trying to create an event that is triggered by page scroll position.

[Here](http://codepen.io/padraic/pen/KpBBYd) is what I have so far on codepen. Here's what I have for the JS:

```
console.log('loaded script - binding to scroll....');
$('.px').scroll(function() {
  console.log('Binded to scroll...');
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log("scroll:" + scroll);
  if (scroll >= 0) {
    $('.pxLayer-base').css('background', 'rgba(197,199,187,' + (scroll/100) + ")");
  }
});
```

But you have to look at the HTML and CSS to understand the issue. I have it ping me that the script is loaded, then again inside the .scroll() function. I get the first ping, but not the second, so I'm thinking that the .scroll() function won't bind to anything I feed it. I've tried $(window), $(document), and many others. It's currently set to $('.px') because that is the div class in which all the parallax magic happens.

So is .scroll() incompatible with my site? Is there a workaround? If you can't tell, I'm basically trying to have the div layers fade into a color as the user scrolls down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery installed? If not, insert this into your HTML head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Or maybe try using an equivalent of the .scroll() listener

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.px', function(){ 
    console.log('scrolling');
});
```

Try wrapping your entire listener in a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.px').scroll(function() {
    console.log('Binded to scroll...');
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log("scroll:" + scroll);
    if (scroll >= 0) {
      $('.pxLayer-base').css('background', 'rgba(197,199,187,' + (scroll/100) + ")");
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Jeez, I'm an idiot. I'm new to jQuery, and all the scripts I've been combining and testing didn't have a document.ready. Works perfectly, thanks!!

Comment: Please select this as answer so as not to leave an open question